# What is "H5" in Egyptian?

Tags: phonology, terminology, egyptian

There seems to be a general consensus that classical Egyptian had four "guttural" or "H-like" phonemes: *h* (building, `/h/`), *ḥ* (wick, `/ħ/`), *ḫ* (placenta?, `/x/`), and *ẖ* (animal's belly, `/ç/`). And the main works that I've seen exploring the historical phonology (e.g. Loprieno) haven't proposed any additional ones, to my knowledge.

However, [the documentation for CLTK's MdC transliterator](https://docs.cltk.org/en/latest/ancient_egyptian.html) seems to mention a fifth:

> Small and Capital H5: almost exclusively used for transliterating demotic script.

What is "H5"? Is this a different name for one of the "standard" phonemes, or a new discovery, or a fringe theory that isn't accepted by the mainstream? Or something else entirely?

Comment: The Wikipedia page on [Demotic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Demotic_(Egyptian)) depicts this as h with circumflex below h̭ but it doesn't give pronunciations of any of the letters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"H5" or "fifth H" is generally transcribed either "h̭" or "ḫ₂", and represents what's very likely a phonemic split in later Egyptian.

At a certain point, Egyptian *ḫ* starts being written in two different ways in group-writing: when it's written with the sign *ḫ* on its own ("ḫ₁"), it corresponds to ϩ in Sahidic Coptic, and when it's written with *ḫ* followed by dual strokes ("ḫ₂"), it corresponds to Sahidic ϣ. For example, *ḫr* "road" is written with *ḫ₁* in group-writing and leads to ϩⲓⲣ in Sahidic, while *mḫr* "box" is written with *ḫ₂* in group-writing and leads to ⲙϣⲓⲣ in Sahidic.

In Demotic, the two are written with different glyphs (descending from the old hieratic *ḫ* uniliteral with and without dual strokes), so Demoticists have given them different transcriptions: *ḫ* versus *h̭*. And given the Sahidic evidence, they do seem to have been phonemically different. But the nature of the distinction isn't entirely clear—the dual strokes may have been used as a generic diacritic to indicate "something is different about this sound" in group-writing—and I haven't found any suggestion for how they might have been pronounced. So if someone finds such a suggestion, please do add another answer!

Comment: (My main source for this is Kilani's _Vocalisation in Group Writing: A New Proposal_.)